# Logstash - kv filter ignored

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am having a problem with kv filter. It is entirely ignored in my if statement.
For debugging purpose i tried to add two tags - one within mutate filter, second in kv.

```
if [message] =~ /^\[ID\]/ {
  mutate { add_tag => [ "id_test_tag" ] }
  kv { add_tag => [ "id_test_tag2" ] }
}
```

Result:

```
"tags" => "id_test_tag"
```

Not sure what is wrong here...

Answer (score 1):

All filters that inherit the base filter class have the add_tag option as one of the "common options" that the base class [provides](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/e4dc82a9b319625f79582730e173c8736d5a1ba6/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb#L207). It is documented for the kv filter [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-add_tag).

The base filter_matched method, which implements the "decoration" functions like add_tag, is [not called](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-kv/blob/9586021bae1fea5b3af1ce8842a3cee76a88ac4d/lib/logstash/filters/kv.rb#L445) unless parsing the source field finds some keys and values. So if the [message] field does not contain the field_split and value_split strings the add_tag will not happen.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation.
I was trying to parse this log with KV and I was adding tags just to test if my condition works.
`[Rule] 'Server - update repository' [Source] 10.10.10.10 [User] _Server [Content] HTTP GET http://example.com`

Will field_split_pattern work in this case? I wanted to create a pattern like: `\[\w+\]\s+` but it does not work right now.

Comment: You  can parse that using `kv { field_split_pattern => "\s\[" value_split_pattern => "\]\s" trim_key => "\[\]" }`